# Logger per instance, bad practice?

Tags: java, logging, static, instance, java.util.logging

I have a class (example FileConfig) which is used at many different places in the program and the class is also part of its (plugin) API. So the class should be very general and broadly useable. I want to use a `Logger` (`java.util.logging.Logger`) in this class. Using a `private static final Logger` instance per class seems to be best practice, as shown in many code samples. In my opinion this is very unflexible in my case. I can think of cases where I or someone using the API wants to use a different `Logger` instance for a particular part of the program. The following code shows my idea to solve this problem.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FileConfig {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(FileConfig.class.getName());
    private Logger logger = LOGGER;

    public void setLogger(Logger logger) {
        if (logger == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("logger cannot be null");
        }

        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

This makes it possible to use a different `Logger` per instance, while the default behavior is still the same as just having the `static Logger` field. Are there any problems with this code? Is there a reason why I should avoid that? Is this bad practice for whatever reason? If yes, why? I would also appreciate your personal opinion about this or suggestion how to improve it.

Comment: Why do you want to use JUL instead of slf4j? And in what *exact* cases would someone want to use a different logger?

Comment: I don't have dependencies so far and I won't need them. I won't use dependencies just for logging. Using SLF4J won't solve my problem, the logger is used in the same way as a JUL logger.

I can't tell you an exact case right now but it would allow using different logger settings or names per instance. There are instances of this class used in completely independent places, so it would make sense to have different loggers in my opinion. It's just more flexible, which is what I would expect from a general class.

Comment: `can't tell you an exact case`: Apply YAGNI. It sounds like what you *really* want is a Multiple Diagnostic Context (MDC) feature, which is one of the main reasons to go with something like slf4j instead of something outdated like JUL. (And if you have *no* dependencies, then either your code is unbelievably trivial or you're reinventing a lot of wheels.)

Comment: That's not helpful. You actually don't know anything about my project and its setup or complexity. I asked a very specific question which I need an answer for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any problems with this code?

There is no thread-safe coordination between threads using the logger and threads changing the logger.  There is no JavaDoc stating the assumptions of usage.

> Is there a reason why I should avoid that?

Having a method `setLogger` that can be invoked after construction might allow messages to be torn between Handlers.  Changing the logger for a class seems like that should require permission check.

> I would also appreciate your personal opinion about this or suggestion how to improve it.

You don't forbid sub-classes so it might be safer to inspect the class name:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FileConfig {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
}
```

Callers that want to use a different logger can subclass the 'FileConfig'.  That allows the subclass to be be created in the namespace of the caller which is usually what you want to achieve when composing objects.

Comment: What do you think about having a constructor with a Logger as argument and a private final Logger field. If another constructor is invoked (or no Logger is supplied), then the field is set to Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()) by default.

Comment: @stonar96 That seems fine too.